# Google Script automatically creating copies

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Form that is being used to track work deployments.  I form is linked to a sheet and the sheet is linked to a script that is triggered upon form submission.  When the form is submitted, my script parses through the responses to get the "Edit URL" so that users can update their response.  Everything is working as excpected except for some reason, I am getting multiple copies of the forms and sheet in my drive that are being automatically created somehow.

This is the function that is triggered when a form is submitted:

---

### Project Namespace

```
function sendEmail(sheet, to, subject, senderName, replyTo, template, cc, bcc, logEmails) {
  if (logEmails) {
    console.log({
        "Requestor" : to,
        "Subject" : subject,
        "Sender" : senderName,
        "Reply To" : replyTo,
        "cc" : cc,
        "bcc" : bcc,
        "template" : template
      });
  }
  else {
    aneis.sendEmails(sheet, to, subject, senderName, replyTo, template, cc, bcc);
  }
}

function testAssignMissingEditUrls() {
  assignMissingEditUrls(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId(),"Changes","xxxxxxxx");
}

function onChangeFormSubmitted(responsesSheet, subsciberSheet, lastEditRow, logEmails) {
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('emailTemplate').getContent();

  var requestor = lastEditRow[aneis.findColumnByHeader(responsesSheet, "Email Address")];
  var changeTo = lastEditRow[aneis.findColumnByHeader(responsesSheet, "Change to")];
  var subject = subjectPrefix + " - " + changeTo;

  var tlName = lastEditRow[aneis.findColumnByHeader(responsesSheet, "Team Lead")];
  var tlEmail = "";
  if (tlName) {
    tlEmail = TLtoEmail[tlName];
  }

  var tlApproved = lastEditRow[aneis.findColumnByHeader(responsesSheet, "Team Lead Approved?")];
  var mgrApproved = lastEditRow[aneis.findColumnByHeader(responsesSheet, "Manager Approved?")];

  var timestampColumn = aneis.findColumnByHeader(responsesSheet, "Timestamp");
  var lastResponseTime = lastEditRow[timestampColumn];

  var submittedOnColumn = aneis.findColumnByHeader(responsesSheet, "Submitted On");
  var submittedByColumn = aneis.findColumnByHeader(responsesSheet, "Submitted By");

  var submittedOn = lastEditRow[submittedOnColumn] || "";
  var submittedBy = lastEditRow[submittedByColumn] || "";

  var firstTime = !submittedBy || !submittedOn;

  if (firstTime) {
    aneis.assignLastFormEditUrl(responsesSheet.getParent().getId(), responsesSheet.getSheetName(), "xxxxxxxxxx");

    // archive original submitter
    submittedOn = lastResponseTime;
    submittedBy = requestor;

    var responsesDataRange = responsesSheet.getDataRange();
    var responsesData = responsesDataRange.getValues();
    var lastdt = (new Date(lastResponseTime)).getTime();

    for (var i = 1; i < responsesData.length; i++) {
      var thisTimestamp = (new Date(responsesData[i][timestampColumn])).getTime();
      if (thisTimestamp == lastdt) {
        responsesDataRange.getCell(i + 1, submittedOnColumn + 1).setValue(submittedOn); // 1 based indexing when setting
        responsesDataRange.getCell(i + 1, submittedByColumn + 1).setValue(submittedBy); // 1 based indexing when setting
        break;
      }
    }

    // Send notification email (first time only)
    var bccList = [];
    var subscriberData = subsciberSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    subscriberData.forEach(function(subscriptionRow){
      var email = subscriptionRow[aneis.findColumnByHeader(subsciberSheet, "Email Address")];
      var emailPref = subscriptionRow[aneis.findColumnByHeader(subsciberSheet, "Email Preferences")];
      if (emailPref == "When anyone submits" && email != requestor) {
        bccList.push(email);
      }
    });

    sendEmail(responsesSheet, submittedBy, subject, senderName, replyTo, htmlTemplate, [], bccList, logEmails);
  }

  if (tlEmail.length > 0) {
    if (tlApproved == "No") {
      var tlApproval_subject = "TL Approval Required - " + changeTo;
      var tlApproval_htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('tlApprovalTemplate').getContent();

      sendEmail(responsesSheet, tlEmail, tlApproval_subject, senderName, replyTo, tlApproval_htmlTemplate, [submittedBy], [], logEmails);
    }
    else if (tlApproved == "Yes" && mgrApproved == "No") {
      var mgrApproval_subject = "APPROVAL REQUIRED - " + changeTo;
      var mgrApproval_htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('mgrApprovalTemplate').getContent();

      sendEmail(responsesSheet, mgrEmail, mgrApproval_subject, senderName, replyTo, mgrApproval_htmlTemplate, [submittedBy, tlEmail], [], logEmails);
    }
    else if (tlApproved == "Yes" && mgrApproved == "Yes") {
      var approved_subject = "Approved - " + changeTo;
      var approved_htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('approvedTemplate').getContent();

      sendEmail(responsesSheet, submittedBy, approved_subject, senderName, replyTo, approved_htmlTemplate, [mgrEmail, tlEmail], [], logEmails);
    }
  }
}

function onPreferenceFormSubmitted() {
  console.log("Preferences were updated... maybe notify the user that they updated their preferences");
}

function onFormSubmitted() {
  var responsesSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Changes");
  var lastEditResponseRow = aneis.findMostRecentEdit(responsesSheet, "Timestamp");
  var lastResponseTime = lastEditResponseRow[aneis.findColumnByHeader(responsesSheet, "Timestamp")];

  var subsciberSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Subscriptions");
  var lastEditSubscriberRow = aneis.findMostRecentEdit(subsciberSheet, "Timestamp");
  var lastSubscriberTime = lastEditSubscriberRow[aneis.findColumnByHeader(subsciberSheet, "Timestamp")];

  if (lastResponseTime > lastSubscriberTime) {
    onChangeFormSubmitted(responsesSheet, subsciberSheet, lastEditResponseRow);
  }
  else {
    onPreferenceFormSubmitted();
  }
```

---

### aneis Namespace

```
function sendEmails(responsesSheet, requestor, subject, senderName, replyTo, htmlTemplate, ccList, bccList) {
  var responsesData = responsesSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var numRows = responsesData.length;
  var headerRow = responsesData[0];
  var lastEditResponseRow = findMostRecentEdit(responsesSheet, "Timestamp");
  var htmlBody = fillTemplate(headerRow, lastEditResponseRow, htmlTemplate);

  // make sure CC list does not also contain the requestor
  var cc = [];
  ccList.forEach(function(c) {
    if (c && c != requestor) {
      cc.push(c);
    }
  });

  // make sure BCC list does not also contain the requestor or anyone also on the CC list
  var bcc = [];
  bccList.forEach(function(b){
    if (b && b != requestor && cc.indexOf(b) < 0) {
      bcc.push(b);
    }
  });

  var message = {
      to: requestor,
      cc: cc.join(","),
      bcc: bcc.join(","),
      name: senderName,
      replyTo: replyTo,
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: htmlBody
  };
  console.info(message);
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}

function findColumnByHeader(sheet, headerName) {
  var headerRow = sheet.getRange("1:1").getValues()[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < headerRow.length; i++) {
    if (headerRow[i] == headerName) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

function assignLastFormEditUrl(responsesSheetId, sheetName, formId) {
  var responsesSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(responsesSheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var form = FormApp.openById(formId);

  var responsesDataRange = responsesSheet.getDataRange();
  var editUrlColumn = findColumnByHeader(responsesSheet, 'Edit URL');
  var timestampColumn = findColumnByHeader(responsesSheet, 'Timestamp');

  var timestamp = new Date(responsesDataRange.getValues()[responsesDataRange.getLastRow() - 1][timestampColumn]).setMilliseconds(0);

  // Get/set the Edit URL
  var resp = form.getResponses();
  for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
    var r = resp[i];
    var rTimestamp = r.getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0);
    if (rTimestamp == timestamp) {
      responsesDataRange.getCell(responsesDataRange.getLastRow(), editUrlColumn + 1).setValue(r.getEditResponseUrl());
      break;
    }
  }
}

function findMostRecentEditRowIndex(responsesSheet, timestampColumnName) {
  var responsesData = responsesSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var tsCol = findColumnByHeader(responsesSheet, timestampColumnName);
  var mostRecentRow = 0;
  var mostRecentDate = new Date("01-01-1900");


  responsesData.forEach(function(row, index) {
    if (index === 0) {
      // Skip the header!
      return;
    }

    var date = new Date(row[tsCol]);
    if (date > mostRecentDate) {
      mostRecentDate = date;
      mostRecentRow = index;
    }
  });

  return mostRecentRow;
}

function fillTemplate(fieldsList, valuesList, template) {
  var retVal = template;
  fieldsList.forEach(function(field, index) {
    var field = "[" + field + "]";
    var fieldValue = "" + valuesList[index];

    if (field != "[Edit URL]") {
      fieldValue = updateHtmlWithWebLinks(fieldValue);
    }
    var fieldMacro = new RegExp(getRegExpEscaped(field), "gm");
    retVal = retVal.replace(fieldMacro, fieldValue);
  });

  return retVal;
}

function getRegExpEscaped(inputString) {
  return inputString.replace("[","\\[").replace("]","\\]").replace("(","\\(").replace(")","\\)").replace("?","\\?").replace(".","\\.").replace("*","\\*");
}

function updateHtmlWithWebLinks(inputHtml) {
  var reWeb = new RegExp("(https{0,1}.*)", "gm");
  return inputHtml.replace(reWeb, function(s) {
    return '<a href="' + s + '">' + s + '</a>';
  });
}
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: I have some questions:
- Can you explain further how does your script create copies of your form and sheet? 
- Does it happen on each execution of the `onFormSubmit` event handler?
- How are you installing the triggers?

Comment: The copy appears to happen every time the `onFormSubmitted` event handler is triggered.  The trigger is installed via the script project and runs "on Form submit" for the associated spreadsheet.

Comment: I really can't see how your code can generate copies of your documents. I think that the problem resides on another portion of your code. Can you please share the full code? In this way I will be able to help you better. Especially the `onChangeFormSubmitted` function. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand it either.  I updated the description with the all the code.  There are some global variables intentionally left out but the overall structure and code path is there.  There are 2 "namespaces", the Project namespace and 'aneis' namespace.  Project namespace is just as it sounds (local to the spreadsheet) and the 'aneis' namespace are common, reusable, functions that are used by other sheets, docs and forms in my google drive.

Comment: Hello Anthony, I really cannot find the cause of this behavior in your code. I really believe it has to be somewhere else. My advice is to contact the [GSuite support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en) and ask them to check on a "weird file appeared on my drive". They will be able to diagnose the root cause of the creation of these files. I hope this helps.